# Reducing a timestamp on just year and month

Tags: r, string, extract, lubridate

I'm trying to extract only the month and year out of a timestamp (for further analysis in QGIS)

Example for a timestamp:
2019-05-29 18:00:28.000

I've tried already the str_extract function (see below) and it worked for reducing the timestamp on just the year. Unfortunaly I do need the month as well and I can not figure out how to do that.
It does not matter whether the timestamp is reduced or a new column with just the year and month is created.

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)


HerrSchmid_Year <- read.csv("HerrSchmid_Snow.csv")
str(HerrSchmid_Year) #has to be data.frame


HerrSchmid_Year$timestamp <- str_extract(HerrSchmid_Year$timestamp,"(\\w+)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ymd_hms()` and convert the string to a date/time column and then extract the month and year. You can set `label` parameter to true if you want month labels. Alternatively, you can try `str_sub()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


 
dat <- tibble(dt_str = c("2021-06-15 23:02:03.000", "2021-07-15 23:02:03.000"))

dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(
    dt = ymd_hms(dt_str),
    mth = month(dt),
    mth_label = month(dt, label = TRUE),
    year = year(dt),
    year2 = str_sub(dt, 1, 4),
    year2 = as.integer(year),
    mth2 = str_sub(dt, 6, 7),
    mth2 = as.integer(mth),
    mth_yr1 = str_sub(dt_str, 1, 7),
    mth_yr2 = paste(year2, mth2, sep = "-")
  )

dat

# # A tibble: 2 x 10
#   dt_str                  dt                    mth mth_label  year year2  mth2 mth_yr1 mth_yr2
#   <chr>                   <dttm>              <dbl> <ord>     <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>   <chr>  
# 1 2021-06-15 23:02:03.000 2021-06-15 23:02:03     6 Jun        2021  2021     6 2021-06 2021-6 
# 2 2021-07-15 23:02:03.000 2021-07-15 23:02:03     7 Jul        2021  2021     7 2021-07 2021-7
```

Comment: Hey Zaw, 
it did not work for some reason. It dosen't gave me any error or waring massages it just didn't do anything to the data.

Comment: That's odd. I see that your date/time also has milliseconds but `ymd_hms()` should be able to capture it effortlessly. Perhaps, you can try using `str_sub()`?  I have updated the answer.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! 
There is just one little tiny thing... is there an option to get month and year in the same column? Otherwise the other program for which I'm preparing the data can not read in the time code correctly

Comment: You can either directly substring from `dt_str` or `paste` year and month together. I have updated the answer.